# Access old("value") in form edit

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.3

I'm currently working on an edit page. My edit perfectly shows the old (product name) input value, like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="product-input">@lang('product.name')</label>
    <input id="product-input" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($product) ? $product->name : '' }}">
</div>
```

My question is, how can I do this with a select? How can I get the old selected option value when editing?

**My code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@lang('product.group')</label>
    <select name="product_group_id" id="product_group_id" class="form-control" ng-model="productGroup" ng-change="changedType(val)">
            <option style="display: none" value="">@lang('product.choose_group')</option>
        @foreach ($product_groups as $product_group)
            <option value="{{$product_group->id}}">{{$product_group->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**Solution**:

Added ng-selected to the option element, like so:

```
@foreach ($product_groups as $product_group)
    <option value="{{$product_group->id}}" ng-selected="{{ isset($product->product_group_id) ? $product->product_group_id == $product_group->id : ''}}">{{$product_group->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the **old value** equals option value and then use **selected** attribute:

```
    @foreach ($product_groups as $product_group)
        <option @if(old('product_group_id') == $product_group->id) selected @endif value="{{$product_group->id}}">{{$product_group->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better considering the first time with default value:

```
<option 
    value="{{$product_group->id}}" 
    {{ old('product_group_id', $product->id) != $product_group->id?: 'selected' }}>
        {{$product_group->name}}
</option>
```